# Is the YEAR function still not SARGable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, optimization

In a book about SQL Server 2014, I was advised to avoid

```sql
SELECT orderid, orderdate, filler
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2014;
```

and prefer

```sql
SELECT orderid, orderdate, filler
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE orderdate >= '20140101'
AND orderdate < '20150101';
```

when there is a clustered index on `orderdate` because using `YEAR` makes the query non-SARGable.

Has this changed since SQL Server 2014? If so, what version did it change in?

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that I would be best off answering questions like this by doing to a DBFiddle website and running the query across multiple versions of SQL Server. If an answer does not prove this wrong, then I will develop that habit.

Comment: It is (still?) not SARGable. Putting a function on a column in the `WHERE` will almost always cause your query to be non-SARGable. You can easily test this by running the able 2 queries and ch cling the execution plans (assuming you have appropriate indexes).

Comment: That is indeed a good habit to use DBFiddle, as is avoiding functions in `WHERE` and `ON` predicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it is still not sargable ([2022 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ajZd7nvC)).

A couple of related requests on the Connect site (wayback machine links) were

- [Make more functions SARGable](http://web.archive.org/web/20161227193447/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable)
- [The optimizer should be able to understand the invertability of built-in intrinsics on dates for the purposes of index sargability](http://web.archive.org/web/20161228021727/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/653206/the-optimizer-should-be-able-to-understand-the-invertability-of-built-in-intrinsics-on-dates-for-the-purposes-of-index-sargability)

But these have never been implemented so far. The response to the second one (which specifically mentions [`YEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) was

> Thanks for the feedback. We'll consider this for a future release, and
> I agree it would be a valuable addition. There are numerous
> workarounds for this though so I don't see it as high priority. E.g.
> use a Date dimension table and join it to the largeTable on the date
> column. Filter on date on the Date dimension before the join. That way
> you can get an index seek during the join to eliminate ranges of data.
>
> Indexed views and columnstore indexes also may be useful for this
> scenario.
>
> Do you know if the competition can do this particular query
> transformation you describe?

To me it does seem like the kind of thing that could have been considered under the SQL Server 2016 "It Just Runs Faster" strapline but presumably it wasn't!.

The new [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function is also not sargable but does at least understand when applying `DATETRUNC` on a column will preserve the ordering of that column - so can [avoid unnecessary sorts when grouping](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/t-sql-queries/date-bucket-datetrunc-improve-time-based-grouping) by year for example.

If this was to be implemented I assume it could well be done in a similar way to the sargability of `CAST` to `DATE` by using the [dynamic seek mechanism](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html).

Even in this case just expressing it as a `>= ... <` range directly is still [more efficient](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea/34052#34052) than just relying on the dynamic seek to sort it out however.